# Installing chrome extension - mac OS

Tags: google-chrome

I would like to install a 3rd party chrome extension. I don't know how to install it, the extension is not available in chromestore. I've found it on github.

Any light on installing this extension. https://github.com/google/chrome-language-immersion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome type `chrome://extensions/` in the address window.

Enable Developer Mode (slider)

New window will open allowing you to add your Extension

[image]

Chrome will prompt you at every browser start if you really want to keep the manually installed extension. This is normal. It is a security feature of Chrome so nobody can install extensions behind your back.

Comment: Your answer worked but probably the extension on github is 4 years old & can't load it. Found kanopy immersion on chromestore, that worked. Many thanks sir  .